# How to remove the blue underline in TextView (Android)

Tags: nativescript

How can I remove the blue underline that appears on a TextView - Android.

I'm ok with it on a TextField - but in a multi-line TextView - looks weird.

Answer (score 3):

Set the color of TextView is the same as background

Answer (score 1):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout backgroundColor="red">
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" />
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
    <TextField hint="" id="tfield" text="tests textfield"/>
   <TextView hint="" id="tview" text="tests textView" editable="true" style="border-color:white; "  />


  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

remove textfield and textview border-bottom is to set background color. This will color up the border too.